# Exponential plotting in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a list of tuples of the form [(a0, b0), (a1, b1), ..., (a_n, b_n)]. The y-values are already calculated based on the x-values - that's how the list of tuples was built. I am trying to plot these data points in an exponential way in order to get an image that justifies the limit as x -> infinity. I have read other users' posts and the main suggestion is to use `curve_fit` from `scipy`. The problem that I am faced with is that `curve_fit` takes three parameters, with the first one being the function that created the y-values.

My function is `math.log N(x)/math.log(x)`, where `N(x)` is the number of nodes containing data at every level of a Tree and `x` is a value defined by the total number of nodes at every level of a Tree. The "formal" definition:

```
lim x->infinity [log N(x)/log(x)]
```

So far I have only managed to plot the points in a polynomial way; as follows:

```
coordinates_set = [] #tuples set containing the coordinates
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)
x_values = [x[0] for x in coordinates_set]
y_values = [y[0] for y in coordinates_set]

polynomial_degree = 4
coeffs = np.polyfit(x_values, y_values, polynomialDegree)
y_poly = np.polyval(coeffs, x)

plt.ylim((-100, 5000))
plt.xlim((-1,1))
plt.plot(x_values, y_values, 'o', label='data points')
plt.plot(x, y_poly, label='polynomial fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The resulting graph:
[image]

Any suggestions for exponential plotting in my case? or any suggestions for a better implementation?

**EDIT**

Here is an example of a few tuples from the `coordinates_set` list:

```
[[0.16666666666666666, -0.0], 
[0.08333333333333333, -1.6736576739067788],
[0.041666666666666664, -2.614706150234702], 
[0.020833333333333332, -2.5468257447958154], 
[0.010416666666666666, -1.5649172897268775],
[0.005208333333333333, -0.13183980802870454]]
```

Also, in the formulation of `lim x-> infinity log N(x)/log(x)`, `N(x)` is provided as a value since I have a different function, `N`, that returns the value.

Comment: "The problem that I am faced with is that curve_fit takes three parameters, with the first one being the function that created the y-values." - can you explain why this is a problem?

Comment: I will always get the error: `Matplotlib: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`

Comment: To clarify, have you tried the formalism here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Specifically, I'm guessing you want $f(x,a,b)=a*exp(b*x)$?

Comment: can you edit your question to provide 5 values of N(x) and x.  Also, is the function for y_values math.log(N(x)) / math.log(x)?  You have written math.log N(x) which would certainly give an error

Comment: I did read the documentation of `curve_fit` but from my understanding f is the function that is passed to `curve_fit` and f is not suitable for that in my case. I did see other users posting something about functions similar to the one you suggested but I am not sure how to use it. Do I need that in this case and pass that instead of my function? Like I said, I did see examples of its usage, but I thought it would not apply to my case.

Comment: Minor note: you have a `list` of tuples, not a `set` of tuples. I know what you mean, but `set`s are another thing in python:)

Comment: Yes; I'm aware of sets. I will make sure to distinguish them better and adjust my terminology.

Comment: Also, it's a bit odd what you're exactly trying to do. I suspect that you're looking for a power-like asymptotic behaviour of `N` on `x`. Is this correct? In this case you probably have to fit a linear function to `logN(logx)`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Also, you mentioned the linear function - that's why I defined `x = np.linspace(0,5,1000)`. Here is where one can see precisely what I am trying to do: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension

Comment: OK, cool. So, as the wiki also notes, you need the `d` in `N(1/n) ≈ C n^d`. This means that `log(N) ≈ d*log(n) +C`, and asymptotics come into play with "as large n as you can do". So, first plot `log N` vs `log x`. If that's fairly linear for large `n` values, you'll be fine. In this case, use `curve_fit` to fit a linear to these data, the slope will be `d`. Alternatively, fit the full exponential to the original data. Or, if you can't figure out `curve_fit`, use `polyfit` with a linear polynomial. What I'm saying is probably "use `polynomialDegree=1` and use the slope".

Comment: Yes but in my case, `x = 1/(d*(2**n))', which is epsilon in the formula posted on Wiki. Right now I am plotting `epsilon` vs. `log(N(epsilon))/log(epsilon)`. In the case of a linear polynomial, I only get a line (which, of course, makes sense).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115886/discussion-between-andras-deak-and-vflav).